# How the confidence score is determined in chatbots [RASA]

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I want know that how the confidence score is calculated for chat bots ?

Answer (score 1):

It Totally depends on the pipeline that you are using in config.yml. You need to dig into each and every component for that. [Rasa Components](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/components)